# Re-render subsequent times in reactjs with fresh json data?

Tags: javascript, json, html, reactjs

After a lot of research and failed attempts, I still cannot figure out how to get a reactjs page to re-render with a subsequent call to the API from a button click on the page (as opposed to just hitting F5).

I have looked at many Stack posts over the past couple of days, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509304/react-render-re-render-two-different-versions-of-state) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664220/reactjs-how-to-call-json-data-with-out-caching) but nothing has shed any light on what I might be doing wrong in this particular case.

I think the problem may be in the way I am trying to "recall" the call to the JSON and the getSate on lines 49 and 52 of the script.

[Here](http://codepen.io/profaneVoodoo/pen/EgjrmP) is my codepen.

Again, all I'm trying to do for the moment is to reload the page, to repeat the exact same operation that already happened on componentDidMount. If I can get this to work, later I will add new sorting rules (the whole reason I'm doing this and not just hitting F5!) but first I just need to get the page to reload again with a button click.

```
<div id="content" >
</div>



var elems = [];



var LeaderList = React.createClass({  
  getInitialState: function() { 
        return{ value:"Sort By Campers' Overall Score"
              }
    },
    render:function(){
    return(
      <div className="container">
      <div id="instructions">
        <section>
    <img id="fccLogo"   src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/freecodecamp_logo.svg"     alt="FreeCodeCamp logo" />    
    <h1 id="title">Leaderboard - The Top 100 FCC "Campers"</h1>
        </section>

        <button type="button" id="sortme" value={this.state.value} onClick={() => this.refs.alldata.reloadAndReSortOnClick()}>{this.state.value}</button>
        </div>
    <AllData ref="alldata"/>
        <Footer />

        </div>
    );
  }
});  

var AllData = React.createClass({

    dataUrl: 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent',
    getInitialState: function() { 
        return {data: []}
    },
    componentDidMount: function(){
      console.log("success!");
        $.getJSON(this.dataUrl, this.handleData)
    },
    handleData: function(data){
        this.setState({data: data}) 
    },

    reloadAndReSortOnClick: function(){
      var buttonsay = document.getElementById("sortme").innerHTML;
      if (buttonsay === "Sort By Campers' Overall Score"){
        document.getElementById("sortme").innerHTML = "Sort By Score in Last 30 Days ";
      }                                                   
      else{document.getElementById("sortme").innerHTML = "Sort By Campers' Total Points";
        }
    },

    render: function(){
      var j = 1;
      var rows = [];

        for(var i=0; i<this.state.data.length; i++){
          var visage = (this.state.data[i].img);
          var tempy = (this.state.data[i].username);
          var recent = (this.state.data[i].recent);
          var overall = (this.state.data[i].alltime);
          rows.push(<tr> <td>{j}</td><td><img src={visage} id="manage_image"/>   </td><td>{tempy}</td><td>{recent}</td><td>{overall}</td></tr>);
          j++;
        }

            return (
        <table id="thetable">
            <thead >
                <tr>
                    <th >Rank</th>
                    <th id="top_campers">Top Campers</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Score in Last 30 Days</th>
                    <th>Overall Score</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
        </table>
      );

    }

});


var Footer = React.createClass({
    render() {
    return (
      <footer>
        <div id="containerfooter">
          <p>Written by <a     href="http://codepen.io/profaneVoodoo/full/dXBJzN/">John Gillespie</a> for Campers</p>
        </div>
      </footer>
    );
  }
  });


ReactDOM.render(
  <LeaderList />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you keep the data of your table in a state variable and update its value when you make the AJAX calls.

```
    getInitialState: function() { 
        return {data: [], sort: "asc"}
    },

    componentDidMount: function(){
      this.loadData()
    },

    loadData: function(){
        var rthis = this
        $.get( 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent?sort=' + rthis.state.sort, function (result) {
          rthis.setState({data: result})
        }) 
    },

    reload: function(){
        this.setState({sort: this.state.sort === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"}, function(){
            this.loadData()
        })
    },

    render: function(){

      var j = 1;
      var rows = [];

        for(var i=0; i<this.state.data.length; i++){
          var visage = (this.state.data[i].img);
          var tempy = (this.state.data[i].username);
          var recent = (this.state.data[i].recent);
          var overall = (this.state.data[i].alltime);
          rows.push(<tr key={'row_'+j}> <td>{j}</td><td><img src={visage} id="manage_image"/></td><td>{tempy}</td><td>{recent}</td><td>{overall}</td></tr>);
          j++;
        }

        return (
          <div>
          <button type="button" id="sortme" onClick={this.reload}>Reload and invert sorting</button>

            <table id="thetable">
                <thead >
                    <tr>
                        <th >Rank</th>
                        <th id="top_campers">Top Campers</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Score in Last 30 Days</th>
                        <th>Overall Score</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
      );
```

PS you may need to add some semicolons

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code that accomplishes what I set out to do (you can also view it in [Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/profaneVoodoo/pen/mAVBLJ)):

```
var LeaderList = React.createClass({  
  getInitialState: function() { 
        return{ value:"Sort By Campers' Overall Score"
              }
    },
    render:function(){
    return(
      <div className="container">
      <div id="instructions">
        <section>
    <img id="fccLogo" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/freecodecamp_logo.svg" alt="FreeCodeCamp logo" />    
    <h1 id="title">Leaderboard - The Top 100 FCC "Campers"</h1>
        </section>
        </div>​<img id="fccLogo" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/freecodecamp_logo.svg" alt="FreeCodeCamp logo" />
    <AllData ref="alldata"/>
        <Footer />

        </div>
    );
  }
});

var AllData = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() { 
        return {data: [], changeddata: [], sort: "asc"}
    },
        componentDidMount: function(){
      this.loadData()
    },

    loadData: function(){
        var rthis = this
        $.get( 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent?sort=' + rthis.state.sort, function (result) {
          rthis.setState({data: result})
        })
    },

  reloadAndReSortOnClick: function(){
    var buttonsay = document.getElementById("sortme").innerHTML;
      if (buttonsay === "Sort By Campers' Overall Score"){
        document.getElementById("sortme").innerHTML = "Sort By Score in Last 30 Days ";
        var rthis2 = this
        $.get( 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/alltime?sort=' + rthis2.state.sort, function (result) {
          rthis2.setState({data: result})
        })
      }
      else{document.getElementById("sortme").innerHTML = "Sort By Campers'  Overall Score";
        var rthis2 = this
        $.get( 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent?sort=' + rthis2.state.sort, function (result) {
          rthis2.setState({data: result})
        })}
    },

    render: function(){

      var j = 1;
      var rows = [];

        for(var i=0; i<this.state.data.length; i++){
          var visage = (this.state.data[i].img);
          var tempy = (this.state.data[i].username);
          var recent = (this.state.data[i].recent);
          var overall = (this.state.data[i].alltime);
          rows.push(<tr> <td>{j}</td><td><img src={visage} id="manage_image"/></td><td>{tempy}</td><td>{recent}</td><td>{overall}</td></tr>);
          j++;
        }

            return (
              <div>
          <button type="button" id="sortme" onClick={this.reloadAndReSortOnClick}>Sort By Campers' Overall Score</button>
        <table id="thetable">
            <thead >
                <tr>
                    <th >Rank</th>
                    <th id="top_campers">Top Campers</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Score in Last 30 Days</th>
                    <th>Overall Score</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
        </table>
                </div>
      );

    }

});


var Footer = React.createClass({
    render() {
    return (
      <footer>
        <div id="containerfooter">
          <p>Written by <a href="http://codepen.io/profaneVoodoo/full/dXBJzN/">John Gillespie</a> for Campers</p>
        </div>
      </footer>
    );
  }
  });


ReactDOM.render(
  <LeaderList />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```